# Option clash: using pdfpages with xcolor

Tags: color, lyx, pdfpages

I am using `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` to alternate table row colors in my thesis.

I have tried to include a `.pdf` file as an Appendix using `pdfpages`, however LyX tells me there is a option clash with `xcolor`.

Is there a known workaround for this issue? I have been stumped for the last 2 hours.

Many thanks

Comment: Try `\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}` in the preamble instead of `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`

Comment: Possible before loading package `classicthesis`.

Comment: @Johannes_B: `classicthesis`??????

Comment: Load `xcolor` *without* options and pass `table` as a class option: `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,table]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}`.